# Drop Down Menu is Only Showing One List Item

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

My drop down menu is only showing one of the sub-menu drop down items. I know my css has something wrong with it, but I cannot figure it out. I have played around with various code and I cannot seem to get it. There is only one sub menu. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
/** MENU */

#menu {
overflow: visible;
border-top: 1px solid #F78F1E;
color: #FFF;
background: F78F1E;
background-color: F78F1E;
}

#menu ul {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style: none;
line-height: normal;
text-align: center;
}


#menu li {
display: inline-block;
background: #F78F1E;
padding: 0;
}

#menu a {
display:block;
background: #F78F1E;
padding: 10px 25px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 700;
color: #fff;
}

#menu a:hover, #menu ul li:hover a {

text-decoration: underline;
background-color: #F78F1E;
}


#menu .active a {
background: #F78F1E;
color: #fff;
}


#menu li ul { 
    overflow: visible;

position: absolute;  
display: none; 
margin:0;
padding:0;
} 
#menu li:hover ul { 
display: block; 
        overflow: visible;

} 
#menu li ul li { 
    overflow: hidden;

float: none; 
display: block; 
z-index:1000;


}
#menu li ul li a { 
    overflow: hidden;

width: 100px; 
position: absolute; 
color: #fff; 
z-index:1000;

}
#menu li ul li a:hover { 
background: #F78F1E;
color: #fff; 
z-index:1000;

}
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="menu">
   <ul id="menu">
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html" accesskey="1" title="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html" accesskey="2" title="">About Us</a></li>
      <li>
         <a href="#Products" accesskey="3" title="">Shop</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#Products" accesskey="4" title="">Monogrammed Tees</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Products" accesskey="5" title="">Monogrammed Hats</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Products" accesskey="6" title="">Acrylic Jewelry</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Products" accesskey="7" title="">Trendy Tees</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" accesskey="8" title="">Fonts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" accesskey="9" title="">Wholesale</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" accesskey="10" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&amp;SESSION=eDeMFvoOQELfChA_tPg6ymvAbg8fdNxijv45dbrmjRhxORvzvSfrusuhbt8&amp;dispatch=50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b081989ce41f911b8b0f9abd5cb813489264cd" accesskey="11" title="">cart</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `position: absolute` from `#menu li ul li a` selector and it will work.

[See an example](http://jsfiddle.net/szx2V/)

Additional notes:

1. You defined 2 identical IDs (`id="menu"`), HTML standard requires unique IDs.
2. You closed 2 divs (`</div>`), but opened only one.
3. So many unnecessary CSS properties which doesn't affect on your design, but can harm in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter some padding at the bottom of the li then the sub menu items will display. In the example below I entered padding-bottom:45px

```
#menu li ul li { 
overflow: hidden;
float: none; 
display: block; 
z-index:1000;
padding-bottom:45px;}
```

I hope this helps!